# Is it possible to deep copy using ES5 JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to deep copy using ES5 JavaScript?

The problem I'm currently having is properties nested more than 2 levels deep appear to be copying by reference instead of by value.

Here's what I've currently implemented to copy ...

```
// Clone an object and return the clone
function clone (obj) {
    var newObj = (obj instanceof Array) ? [] : {};
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if(typeof obj[prop] === 'object') {
            newObj[prop] = clone(obj[prop]);
        }
        newObj[prop] = obj[prop]
    }
    return newObj;
};
```

And here's the code used to test:

```
const a = { a: 1, b: { c: 2 }};
const b = clone(a);

a.a = 10;
b.a == a.a; // false

a.b = 10;
b.b == 10; // false

a.b.c = 10;
a.b.c == b.b.c; // true
```

The last one changed the value of `c` in both `a` and `b` objects. The `c` property appears to be a reference type.

How can I ensure that all values are copied by value and are not references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are **cloning nested objects, but then overwrite them again** with the original object:

```
if(typeof obj[prop] === 'object') {
    newObj[prop] = clone(obj[prop]);
}
newObj[prop] = obj[prop]
```

---

Try this instead:

```
if(typeof obj[prop] === 'object') {
    newObj[prop] = clone(obj[prop]);
} else {
    newObj[prop] = obj[prop]
}
```

Comment: Holy christ. It's been a long day! But thank you for spotting that. Works.

Answer (score 4):

You can always use the poor man's deep clone by stringifying and then parsing:

```js
function clone (obj) {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
};

const a = { a: 1, b: { c: 2 }};
const b = clone(a);

a.a = 10;
console.log(b.a == a.a); // false

console.log(a.b = 10);
console.log(b.b == 10); // false

console.log(a.b.c = 10);
console.log(a.b.c == b.b.c); // true
```

Using stringify/parse doesn't copy functions and RegExps, hence the "poor man". A better option is to use a module, such as [clone](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clone) that can clone everything.

Comment: Note: don't forget this won't copy `functions` or `RegExp`

Comment: Also this is very slow.

Comment: Note that _very slow_ is always relative.

Answer (score 2):

Using ES5

> var a = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(b))

Using ES6

> var a = Object.assign(b)

Using Underscore/Lodash

> var a = _.map(b, _.clone)

Comment: `Object.assign(b)` this only performs a shallow copy